# Wishart PDF for 1000 row and 8 column

Tags: r, matlab

I have a data set that is a composite of 8 columns and 1000 rows. How can I calculate the Wishart PDF using Matlab or R? I am confused by the  parameters: if

- `n` is the degree of freedom (=8)
- `S` = inverse covariance matrix`
- `W` = Data ( 1000x8) or should it be the variance-covariance matrix of the data?

  ```
  function f = WishartPDF(W,nu,S)
     N=size(W,1);
     Arg=[nu-N+1:nu];
     K=2^(nu*N/2)*pi^(N*(N-1)/4)*prod(gamma(Arg/2)); 
     f = 1/K * (det(S))^(-nu/2)*(det(W))^((nu-N-1)/2)*
         exp(-1/2*trace(inv(S)*W));
  end
  ```

Comment: Doesn't look like R code, and the question seems rather imprecise. Are you merely having difficulty finding a package with an rWishart or a pWishart function?

Comment: @42 the function above is in Matlab, and the dwishart which is the R: function in R: dwish(W, v, S)  has three argument, my data is 1000 X 8 and i should use wishart over covariance matrix , so  in this case what are the value of the argument , if  W=to the cov ( data) , and n = degree of freedom , what is the value of scale matrix  ( S)  in this case is it  the inverse of the co variance matrix ??

Comment: The help pages for R density functions usually have worked examples.

Comment: @42 No the worked example is not clear , its just only a  symmetric matrix as an argument

Comment: Covariance matrices usually are symmetric. I'd say the lack of clarity rests with you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Wishart density function calculator in base R, but there is one in the `MCMCpack` package.  `library("MCMCglmm"); ?dwish` shows the parameters as

> - W: Positive definite matrix W (p x p).
> - v: Degrees of freedom (scalar).
> - S: Inverse scale matrix (p x p).

So if you have data `dd`, its likelihood under a given Wishart distribution would be

```
dwish(var(dd), v=8, S=S)
```

I'm not sure what your confusion is over `S`; as `?dwish` says

> The mean of a Wishart random variable with ‘v’ degrees of freedom and inverse scale matrix ‘S’ is vS.

In other words, if the mean variance-covariance matrix is W, then you should input W/v as your inverse scale matrix.

Comment: @ Ben Thank you for your answer :                                                                             W = The covariance matrix  of my data  ,                                                                                                     v= degree of freedom  and its 8 i have 8 sample ,                                                       so  S = Cov/8 ?? this is the scale

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do (neither does @42-).  The likelihood (probability density of observing a given set of data) is based on parameters, in this case `v` and `S`.  You have to specify `S` yourself; what makes sense depends on what you're trying to do. It *might* make sense to compute the likelihood assuming that the mean of the variance-covariance distribution is equal to the observed variance-covariance (in which case the expression for the PDF would also simplify considerably), but I really don't know.

Comment: iam Trying to model  Bayesian for my Data set , and the prior is wishart for the covariance matrix which is ( symmetric and positive definitive ) and Normal for the mean, since wishart PDF need three argument :   covariance  ,  data , and degree of freedom , and in most of the example the data was ( symmetric and positive definitive) this is the swishart condition, so my covariance matrix is my data , and i just want to know what will be the third argument value which is  : S , W( X, n , S) :  so for the prior over the covariance now we have W( cov, n, cov/n) .